# How to send email by using Exchange server in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I am migrating a classic asp application to a new server, however smtp server is not allowed in the new server, can someone give me a tips about how to send email via the exchange server?

Comment: What version of exchange? Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP's [CDOSYS component](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp) has a remote server parameter you could use to send emails via the Exchange server on port 25.

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```